# Many to many primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Class:

```
public class BranchAds
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("branch")]
    public int branch_id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("ad")]
    public int advertisement_id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Branch branch { get; set; }
    public virtual Advertisement ad { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("start_time")]
    public DateTime start_time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("end_time")]
    public DateTime end_time { get; set; }

    public DateTime date { get; set; }

}
```

This error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.BranchAds'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BranchAds'. The duplicate key value is (1, 26).

Happens when I try to insert another BranchAds using the same keys.. Well I should since theoretically this is a many to many (junction) table. However the database seems unaware of this.

Why am I doing it this way? Because I need custom fields in the many to many table.

What can I do to resolve this? Without adding a `[Key]` to the BranchAds class.

Comment: Shouldn't it has its own BranchAdsID ?

Comment: No why? Creating a many to many doesn't require its own `id`. Take for a example just having both tables referencing eachother as `ICollections`...

Comment: because normally for each pair (x,y) of the foreign keys, it can only appear once. Now you need repeating for several times because of custom fields or whatever, then you have to use something to differentiate two records with same pair value?

Comment: If there can be duplicate branch/ad in this table then clearly this is not a composite key column. What's different between these two records? The start time? Add that to your key columns.

Answer (score 0):

If `BranchAds` is your intermediate table then i don't see any PK defined on your object. Have you enforced a composite PK constraint (branch + ad) on a DB level?

Comment: Another thing, why you dont want to add a PK (let it be just an autoincrement) on the BranchAds?